# Mongoose "Operation `registers.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms" when start with forever

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-server

I am running a node server linked to a MongoDB Atlas database and it works just fine if I run it on local or on my local server with the command `node index.js` but if I try to run it with forever or nodemon, it runs OK, I can see the app, but when I enter a path for a GET request, the buffering timed out error appears.

This dose does not happen in the previous two cases.

The code:

```
const ENTRYPOINT = `mongodb+srv://${ process.env.MONGO_USER }:${ 
process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD }@${ process.env.MONGO_SERVER_NAME }.dnnpo.mongodb.net/${ process.env.MONGODB_DATABASE_NAME }?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

mongoose.connect( ENTRYPOINT, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true } )
    .then( () => console.log( `Connection established! We are online!` ) )
    .catch( () => console.log( `Database connection failed` ) );
```

I must also add that I am firing the script via an .sh script that is fired at startup/reboot. I am using an Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS.

The script:

```
#!bin/bash

echo "Deploying babilon-api..."

forever -a start /PATH-TO-MY-FILE/index.js

echo "babilon-api started!"
```

UPDATE: Afters some troubleshooting, I managed to pull out some logs from my `forever script` and I found out that for some reason, I am not connecting to the MongoDB Atlas database.

LOGS with `forever start index.js`:

```
listening at 8000
Database connection failed
```

LOGS with `node index.js`:

```
listening at 8000
Connection established! We are online!
```

I still don't understand why that is.

Comment: TLDR: you need a forward slash before `bin` in the first line of your script

Comment: Like: `#!/bin/bash` ??

Comment: Yes, `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: I don't know if that will solve my problem, but it is good to know. :D

Comment: Yeah. Still the same error. Even if I try calling via JS, I get the same error.

Comment: To be fair, I can see the page that is served. But when I call the API path, the error appears. And I called CORS globally to be sure I am not messing anything up.